# PHP: add year if missing

Tags: php, date

I am pulling a date and it only has the month and day. I need to add the year before saving to database. The dates being pulled only go as far a year off. Is there a way to do this?

The way I am receiving the date is Nov 12 or "M d"

Comment: Could you edit your question to show your data format as it needs to be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the year can be 2010 or 2009 right?

```
if (strtotime($date . date('-Y')) > time()) {
    // year ago
    $date .= date('-Y', strtotime('last year'));
} else {
    $date .= date('-Y');
}

// date('-Y') will return -2010 or -2009
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said the dates can't be greater than a year ago, then if the date is greater than today counting only month and day, it's from last year.  Else, this year.